# Excel text to rows using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, text-to-column

I have a concat formula returning me a comma separated list of names in a cell

```
=concat(A2:A10 & " ,") returning [john, jack, jill] in the cell
```

Is there a way to add to this formula to expand to

```
john
jack
jill
```

in a column like that above?

Comment: If you have Office365 (or Excel 2021) you can simply write `=A2:a10` in a single cell and the results will spill down.  Earlier versions of Excel, without dynamic arrays, will require a formula in each cell where you want to show a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the separator to be a line break `=CONCAT(A2:A10 & CHAR(10))` or `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,P3:P5)`

The target cell needs to be set to Wrap Text for the line breaks to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know CHAR(10) was how to add a newline, thats helpful. However ideally i'd be able to get the values in separate cells.

Comment: I thought you wanted them in the same cell (can you put a screenshot with an example of how you want it to work?)

Answer (score 0):

I used Power Editor to convert the cell into rows